# header files, macros and inline functions c++

Tags: c++

I have problems doing an exercise involving c++ header files, macros and inline functions.
Requirements below.

1. Create a header file with name "Max.h"
2. Max.h includes a macro with name "mMax". "mMax" returns max. of 2 integers.
3. Max.h includes an inline function with name "fMax". "fMax" returns max. of 2 integers.
4. Call fMax and mMax in main.cpp.

Here is my code. It doesn't work. Please help.

Max.h

```
#ifdef MAX_H
#define MAX_H

#define mMax(x, y)((x > y) ? x : y;)

inline int fMax(int x, int y)
{
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Max.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << fMax(1, 2) << '\n';
    cout << mMax(1, 2) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define mMax(x, y)((x > y) ? x : y;)` removed the semicolon at end. `#define mMax(x, y)((x > y) ? x : y)`

Comment: *Here is my code. It doesn't work.* is not a suitable problem description. In what way **specifically** does it *not work*?

Comment: Use a good C++ compiler, eg. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with warnings and debug info (so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) and a good debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) ....) Of course read their documentation, and read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). StackOverflow is not a *do-my-homework* website. See http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: Try `#define mMax(x, y) ((x > y) ? x : y)` or full code in action https://ideone.com/TPmhQ2

Answer (score 2):

Your header guard is backwards.  You wrote:

```
#ifdef MAX_H
#define MAX_H

// Header body

#endif
```

This means the header body is only evaluated if `MAX_H` is *already* defined.

What you actually need is to test that `MAX_H` is *not* defined:

```
#ifndef MAX_H
```

To summarize:

- `#ifdef` is short for "if defined"
- `#ifndef` is short for "if not defined"

It has also been pointed out in the comments that your macro contains a stray semi-colon.  That should be removed:

```
#define mMax(x, y) ((x > y) ? x : y)
```

Because macros can substitute just about anything for `x` and `y`, it's also fairly standard practice to put them in parentheses:

```
#define mMax(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))
```